# Pagination on wordpress template search does not work when i exclude category

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I use the code below to exclude a category from my wordpress search results.

```
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( "s=$s&paged=$paged&cat=-35" );
```

But i dont get the pagination at the end of results. How should i modify the search.php in order to show the pagination and exclude the category as well? Pagination works in search results if you remove the two lines i mentioned but i need them to exclude the category.

Below is the search.php code...any help appreciated.

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#search-result
 *
 * 
 */

get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php

        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts( "s=$s&paged=$paged&cat=-35" );
        $archive_content_classes = apply_filters( 'islemag_archive_content_classes', array( 'islemag-content-left', 'col-md-9' ) );
        ?>
        <div
        <?php

        if ( ! empty( $archive_content_classes ) ) {
            echo 'class="' . implode( ' ', $archive_content_classes ) . '"'; }
?>
>
    <div class="post-section islemag-template1">

    <div class=" islemag-template1-posts smaller-nav no-radius">
        <?php
        echo '<div style="font-size:50px;">
        Results</div>';
        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
            $wp_query->the_post();

            $choosed_color = array_rand( $colors, 1 );
            $category      = get_the_category();
            $postid        = get_the_ID();
        ?>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-image text-left">
            <figure>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
            </figure> <!-- End figure -->
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body text-left">
                        <span class="panel-shopname">
                <a style="color:grey;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <?php the_field('add_your_brand'); ?>
                </a>
            </span><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><h4 class="panel-promotitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="left-cell promo-price">
                <?php the_field('product_price'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="right-cell">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-success
                ">Go&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-external-link-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <?php

            endwhile;

        ?>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should paste below code to your active theme's `function.php` to exclude category.

```
function wcs_exclude_category_search( $query ) {
  if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
    return;

  if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-35' );
    $query->set('paged', ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 );
    $query->set('posts_per_page',6);
  }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wcs_exclude_category_search', 1 );
```

And add `the_posts_navigation();` after `endwhile;` in your code.

Remove `the_posts_navigation();` and add below code there

```
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'before_page_number' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">'.$translated.' </span>'
) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have put the code as you said. The code works but i dont get this specific pagination... https://imgur.com/a/mCBBPgJ . This image shows how the pagination in other pages shows up. Instead i get Older and Newest posts labels. Is there a way to get pagination like the image? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. I get the numbers check image https://imgur.com/a/Vmhl7Lq . But i dont get the styling like this imgur.com/a/mCBBPgJ . Is there any way to get the styling as well like the second image?

Comment: you need to add css for that style and please upvote if this answer helps you.